# 86. Merge sorted array JS

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am doing this problem
https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/description/

and this is:

> You are given two integer arrays nums1 and nums2, sorted in
> non-decreasing order, and two integers m and n, representing the
> number of elements in nums1 and nums2 respectively.
>
> Merge nums1 and nums2 into a single array sorted in non-decreasing
> order.
>
> The final sorted array should not be returned by the function, but
> instead be stored inside the array nums1. To accommodate this, nums1
> has a length of m + n, where the first m elements denote the elements
> that should be merged, and the last n elements are set to 0 and should
> be ignored. nums2 has a length of n.
>
> Input: nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3 Output:
> [1,2,2,3,5,6] Explanation: The arrays we are merging are [1,2,3] and
> [2,5,6]. The result of the merge is [1,2,2,3,5,6] with the underlined
> elements coming from nums1.

For input of
nums1 =[0]
m=0
nums2 = [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCfqe.png)
n = 1

[image]

i don't know why it is returning [0]

when i am doing nums2 = [...nums1]

can you please help me

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number} m
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
 */
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
   
    if(m==0){
        nums1 = [...nums2]
        return;
    }
    let placement = nums1.length-1
    let compare1 = m-1
    let compare2 = n-1
    while(compare1>0 && compare2>0){
        if(nums1[compare1]<nums2[compare2]){
            nums1[placement] = nums2[compare2]
            placement -=1
            compare2 -= 1
        }

        if(nums1[compare1]>nums2[compare2]){
            nums1[placement] = nums1[compare1]
            placement -=1
            compare1 -= 1
        }
        if(nums1[compare1] == nums2[compare2]){
            nums1[placement] = nums1[compare1]
            placement -=1
            nums1[placement] = nums2[compare2]
            placement -=1
            compare1 -=1
            compare2 -=1
        }
    }
    return nums1
};
```

Comment: `num1 = [...num2]` doesn't modify the array in place, it instead replaces the array with a new array that is local to the function (the caller can't see it). Also, you're making it needlessly complicated. `const merge = (nums1, m, nums2, n) => { nums1.splice(m, Infinity, ...nums2.slice(0, n)); nums1.sort((a,b) => a-b); };`

Answer (score 1):

The code challenge requires you to *mutate* the given array `nums1`, but your code assigns to `nums1` (instead of mutating the array it referenced), so now you have lost the possibility to still access and mutate the original array. Although you have a `return nums1`, the caller does not look at the return value, but will use the reference it has to the original array and see that nothing has changed inside of it. Note the following phrase in the code challenge (I highlight):

> The final sorted array **should not be returned by the function**, but instead be stored inside the array `nums1`.

Your code has some other issues as well:

- When the `while` condition becomes false, it might be that `compare2 == 0`, which means the value `nums2[compare2]` has not been consulted yet. So that `>0` should really be `>=0`.
- When the `while` condition becomes false, it might be that `compare1 < 0`, but `compare2` is still some positive number, meaning that some values in `nums2` have not been moved to `nums1`. As you want to move **all** values from `nums2` to `nums1`, the `while` condition should be `compare2 >= 0` only. Then the body of the `while` loop should check if `compare1 >= 0`, but this should not be a reason to quit the loop.

  When you have fixed this, there is also no more need to have the special case at the start of the function, and you can remove that `if` block.
- The different `if` blocks should better be mutually exclusive, as otherwise you risk that  `compare2` becomes negative in the first `if` block, and although it would work out fine, it is better to just avoid making comparisons with `undefined`.
- The last block that checks for equality is overkill. If you make the second block an `else` to the first block, then there is no more need to check for equality: it would be dealt with in the `else` block, and the next iterations will take care of the rest.
- Once you have the `if..else`, then note that `placement--` is always executed exactly once in each iteration of the loop, so it can be moved out of the `if..else` blocks.
- Please take the habit to terminate statements with semicolon. Although there is the [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) procedure, you don't want to make your code's interpretation dependent on the quite complex rules it follows.

Here is your code corrected with the points mentioned above:

```
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
    let placement = nums1.length - 1;
    let compare1 = m - 1;
    let compare2 = n - 1;
    while (compare2 >= 0) { // Make sure all of nums2 is moved!
        // If nothing more in nums1, then also copy from nums2
        if (compare1 < 0 || nums1[compare1] < nums2[compare2]) {
            nums1[placement] = nums2[compare2];
            compare2 -= 1;
        } else { // Use else, and no specific case for equality
            nums1[placement] = nums1[compare1];
            compare1 -= 1;
        }
        placement -= 1; // This is common to all cases
    }
};
```